# VBA Color entire row based on the ColorIndex in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where column `E` consists of `ColorIndex`

I have extracted the color index from the cells in Sheet1 using below code,

```
Function BGCol(ThisCell As Range) As Long
BGCol = ThisCell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

and pasted the `ColorIndex` value sto `Sheet2`. How can I color the entire rows based on the `ColorIndex` that I now got. The values are `-4142`,`19`,`35`,`36`,`38`, and `43`. I have a table in Sheet2 where column `E` consists of `ColorIndex` values.

Comment: How did you try to color the rows and why did it not work? Which error did you get? Please include your attempt. If you don't know how the code would look like you can use the Macro Recorder to get an idea how this would work.

Comment: Try something like `ThisCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142`.

Comment: Did you really mean entire row or entire row of table?

Comment: @QHarr just the entire row, e.g. the whole row of 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something like this will work:**

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Interior.ColorIndex = Range("E2").Value
```

Put it in a Loop to and change the Row Index and Range Index.

**Like:**

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")

For i = 1 To 100

     .Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = .Range("E" & i).Value

Next

End With
```